# Binding only works at first TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

I try to change DataGridColumnHeader, which depends on Combobox value, but it only works at the first tabItem. If I reorder columns - it will be works only for first tabItem. What should i do? My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Second">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Code sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42075250/wpfTabDatagrid.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header is basically used to give hard coded values .

use HeaderTemplate :

```
   <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Second">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>                                              
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                         <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>                            
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```